# How to get current screen refresh rate with adb commands?

Tags: android, adb

Is it feasible?
prefer the common commands to run in user, userdebug and eng products.

Answer (score 0):

One can get the refresh rate using the below command:

```
adb shell dumpsys display | grep -i mphys | cut -d ',' -f 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Some devices may have variable refresh rate you can obtain using

```
adb shell dumpsys display | tr ',' '\n' | awk -F= '/^ fps/ {v[$2]=1} END {for (r in v) print r}''
```

giving

```
60.0
120.00001
```